# cannot chose any application in "Open With" for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, file-association, default-settings

I usually use `NotePad++` as my default text editor. I am using Windows 10, and for example I like to set `.config` files to open using NotePad++.  Usually, in other version of windows you would click on `Open with...` and choose.  While I do have the `Open with...` option, it only allows me to select a few applications, or an option to `Choose from store`, which doesn't allow me to select Notepad++.  Is there any way to get the usual selection for any application back?

Answer (score 0):

Beneath **Choose from store** you should have **More apps** and then **Look for another app on this PC**

Just try to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Associate a file type or protocol with a program .cfg

Look for another app on this PC
navigate to notepad++ location